# Implement unique nodes of the same name in Tikz Trees?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I am attempting to make a binary tree representation of a scheme expression. However, I noticed that I cannot repeat the word "cons" as a unique node. The tree will simply tie all subsequent nodes from the second cons to the first cons. I named them con and cons here to show how I want it to come out without naming the rest, to avoid showing the disaster that happens when I do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\graph[binary tree layout]{
  con -- {   
    1 ,
   cons -- {
      l -- {
        m -- { n, o },
        p -- { q, r }
      }, 
      s -- {
        v -- {w, x},
        y -- {z}
      }
    }
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: binarytree]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which nodes are supposed to contain `cons` and which not, so I made them all `cons` just to be on the safe side. Each unique node needs a unique name. But the content of the node need not be unique.

[image: many cons]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{courier}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\graph[binary tree layout]{
  con/"cons" -- {
    1/"cons" ,
   cons -- {
      l/"cons" -- {
        m/"cons" -- { n/"cons", o/"cons" },
        p/"cons" -- { q/"cons", r /"cons"}
      },
      s/"cons" -- {
        v/"cons" -- {w/"cons", x/"cons"},
        y/"cons" -- {z/"cons"}
      }
    }
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```